# query for number of data within same shift

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

This is my timer table in Access:
[image: timer table]

I am trying to get the COUNT of CTLog with the same ShiftLog and ModelLog. There are two shifts: Shift A is 7.00am - 6.59pm(within same day) while Shift B is 7pm to 6.59am(until the next day).

I have no problem in getting COUNT of CTLog for Shift A using

```
select COUNT(*) AS total from timer where ShiftLog = @sl and TodayDate = @dtl and ModelLog = @m;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@sl", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = shiftlabel.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@td", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@m", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = mlb.Text;
```

But with this kind of query I could not get the count of Shift B. How to query the data of Shift B when the date has changed to the next day(including the data after 12am, from 12:01am until 6.59am)?

Comment: Maybe build a from and to date/time. Something like: `ShiftLog = @s1 AND DateTimeLog BETWEEN @dt1 & " 19:00:00" AND @dt1 + 1 & " 6:00:00"`

Comment: @June7 Hi I have figured out a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new column for ShiftStart and ShiftEnd and insert as follow:

```
const string sql = @"INSERT INTO timer(DateTimeLog, ShiftLog, CTLog, WorkcellLog, ModelLog, StationLog, HourID, TodayDate, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd)VALUES(@d, @shift, @ct, @wc, @wm, @ws, @hid, @td, @ss, @se)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDbType.Date).Value = d;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@shift", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = shiftlb.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ct", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = timerlb.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@wc", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = wclb.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@wm", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = mlb.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ws", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = slb.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hid", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = h;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@td", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = today;
if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 7 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) < 19) //Shift A
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 7 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 1859 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
}
else if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 1 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) < 7) //Shift B 1xxam to 659am
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 19 + "&" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 659 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
}
   else if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 19 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) <= 24) //Shift B 7xxpm to 12xxam
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 19 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 659 + "&" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
}
```

Then get the output with similar approach:

```
const string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timer WHERE  ShiftLog = @sl AND ShiftStart = @ss AND ShiftEnd = @se AND ModelLog = @m";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sl", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = shiftlb.Text;    
if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 7 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) < 19) //Shift A
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 7 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 1859 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }
else if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 1 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) < 7) //Shift B 1xxam to 659am
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 19 + "&" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 659 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }
else if (int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) >= 19 && int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H")) <= 24) //Shift B 7xxpm to 12xxam
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 19 + "&" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@se", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = 659 + "&" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
    }
cmd.Parameters.Add("@m" ,OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = mlb.Text;
```